# Scrapy Run code before loading settings.py

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, web-crawler

I have a web crawler that utilizes proxies. I have a script that generates a list of 100 valid proxies, and then I am setting that list as the proxy source in settings.py. My question, is that currently I manually run a script that generates that file, and then I run the crawler.

Does anyone know where I would put that code if I want it to run PRIOR to settings.py being "processed"? I don't want to manually have to run that script before I run the crawler as I want it to be self contained.
`ROTATING_PROXY_LIST_PATH = 'C:\\Users\\cmdan\\Desktop\\Spiders\\Michael Mitarotonda\\proxies.txt'`

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can we see the code structure of your crawler ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Docs explain the method to [Run Scrapy from a script](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/practices.html#run-scrapy-from-a-script). That means it should allow you to do some other operations, such as your proxy script, before running your crawler.

You might want to define your crawler inside this script, or you might want to import your crawler, both are okay.

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess

# if you want to import your spider
# from project.spiders import myspider

class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    # Your spider definition
    ...

# here comes your script, setting the value of
# ROTATING_PROXY_LIST_PATH

process = CrawlerProcess(settings={
    "FEEDS": {
        "items.json": {"format": "json"},
    },
    "ROTATING_PROXY_LIST_PATH": "path-to-file",
})

process.crawl(MySpider)
process.start() # the script will block here until the crawling is finished
```

Comment: Thanks I appreciate it. I considered doing this, and I think it's going to be the best bet. I appreciate this. I was hoping to bundle this all inside the crawler itself, Thanks!